# How to calculate a flexible team capacity and have the sprint capacity adapt to it?

Tags: scrum, agile, planning, resource-planning, safe

I am planning a Program Increment of 3 Months and I have a team of people with a variety of skills.

Basically, we have 3 categories in which each developer is differently skilled: UI, Backend & Devops.

- We know the capacity of each developer for each sprint. (in Story points [SP])
- We know how strong each developer is in which category. (in %)
- We know each User Story (US), their estimations in Story points (1SP ~ 8hours) and their category.

We now want to plan the sprints in such a way, that we respect our capacity in each category and that our developers can't clone themselves.

Up until now we just calculated a sprint capacity, assigned US to this Sprint and subtracted the estimation of that US from that capacity.

The problem with that is, that in a team of 10 people only 4 can do tasks in the category of devops. That means we have a capacity of let's say 10SP per Sprint and our total capacity would be 30 SP.

However, these 4 people are also skilled UI developers. Meaning if I assign a devops ticket to the sprint, it reduces the capacity of the UI  as well.

My problem is how to adaptively calculate the remaining capacity of each category.

**So I give the following example for a calculation that I am trying to do:**

Capacity of an employee in a Sprint:

| Employee | Sprint 1 | Sprint 2 | Sprint 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 SP | 6 SP | 8 SP |
| B | 8SP | 5 SP | 9 SP |
| C | 10 SP | 10 SP | 10 SP |
| D | 10 SP | 0 SP | 10 SP |
| E | 10 SP | 5 SP | 5 SP |

Estimated Skill of an developer in a category:

| Employee | UI | Backend | Devops |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0% | 50% | 100% |
| B | 100% | 0% | 100% |
| C | 20% | 50% | 80% |
| D | 100% | 100% | 0% |
| E | 30% | 50% | 50% |

Potential Capacity per Sprint  (Calculated by SUMPRODUCT() in Excel)

| Sprint | UI | Backend | Devops | Total (Sum()) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sprint 1 | 23 SP | 25 SP | 31 SP | 48 SP |
| Sprint 2 | 8.5 SP | 10.5 SP | 21.5 SP | 26 SP |
| Sprint 3 | 22.5 SP | 21.5 SP | 27.5 SP | 42 SP |

Now with have these 3 US:

- Task 1: 8SP (UI)
- Task 2: 16SP (BE)
- Task 3: 10SP (Devops)

So let's add Task 1 to the 1. Sprint:

| UI | UI SP | Backend | Backend SP | Devops | Devops SP | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| task 1 | 8SP |  |  |  |  | 8 SP |
| Total SP Used | 8 SP |  | 0 SP |  | 0 SP | 8 SP |
| Capacity | 23 SP |  | 25 SP |  | 31 SP | 48 SP |
| Remaining SP | 15 SP |  | 25 SP |  | 23 SP | 40 SP |

This one is easy because Employee B can take that US completely in Sprint 1
but you can already see that the remaining capacity of Devops is lowered aswell.

Let's add Task 2:

| UI | UI SP | Backend | Backend SP | Devops | Devops SP | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| task 1 | 8SP | Task 2 | 16SP |  |  | 24 SP |
| Total SP Used | 8 SP |  | 16 SP |  | 0 SP | 24 SP |
| Capacity | 23 SP |  | 25 SP |  | 31 SP | 48 SP |
| Remaining SP | 4.6 SP |  | 9 SP |  | 11.4 SP | 24 SP |

This one is a lot more complicated as more than on employee will work on that task.
Let's Say Employee A, C, D will work on it:

- A will do: 5 SP of work using 10 SP. => Devops cap. -10SP
- C will do: 1 SP of work using 2 SP.  => UI cap. -0.4 SP & devops cap: - 1.6 SP
- D will do: 10 SP of work using 10 SP. => UI cap. -10 SP

However, I could choose a different selection of Employees to do all the tasks.

So my question is:

**Is there a formula that can give a good approximation of the remaining capacity, based on the overall capacity, individual capacity and individual categorized skills?**

Comment: You're not doing Scrum. What you are trying is to assume that SP correspond to work hours (they do not) and make a full-utilization plan from that. This won't work, ever. It is nice that your team (I hope you mean your team with "we") has estimated the backlog items and has a (likely not very accurate) estimate of their velocity, now let them pick items at the beginning of each sprint as Scrum prescribes. Don't plan everything ahead of time, or you're in for some very unpleasant surprises.

Comment: Velocity is a *team* metric, not an individual productivity metric. Tasking *into* a Sprint rather than pull-based Sprint Planning is also an anti-pattern. I'm not sure how much real help you'll get unless you are willing to let go of some of these preconceived notions first.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Well the inaccuracy of the estimation is of course one thing to deal with. But we got quite good with it. Not perfekt, but we still have some idea what can be done when. However we have Clients, that want stuff to happen in specific time frames, so we need to plan ahead, so we know what we can promise. In other words. we do have scrum, but we also have to plan ahead. For that we need to calculate the capacity, and the accurate the better.

Comment: Why are you estimating in Story points, when you assume man-hours anyway and plan that a specific developer can do a specific number of story points? The whole point of story points is to *not* have that by having an abstraction. Why aren't you simply calculating in man-hours, if you don't use any of the story points benefits anyway?

Comment: Mainly Selling/Defence and its project dependent. We don't do that in every project. It mostly depends on how old the project is, and how experienced the developers are. So this project is older with experienced developers, so their performance is predictable. Basically, you could say we sell story points, giving us more flexibility but we correlate it with hours as much as possible to predict the budget and capacity needed. Basically, my clients want us to be predictable and I want my team utilized efficiently meaning that few devs shouldn't be overworked in one sprint.

Comment: It also doesn't matter to me to make this calculation in the sprint planning or at the beginning of the PI. The calculation will be the same. The difference is that people are interested in the results at the beginning of the PI and my team & I are interested in it in the sprint planning, because we know if the new US can be promised in the sprint and who is over or underbooked.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: Frame challenge. [Use Scrum](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html).

### Try to use Scrum

> In other words. we do have scrum, but we also have to plan ahead

You say you're doing Scrum, right? (Though others here disagree.)
Well, before you start [assuming you know everything and that some parts of Scrum are unnecessary](https://ronjeffries.com/xprog/articles/jatbaseball/), [first try out Scrum as it's intended, then master it, and **only then** try to adapt it to your situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuhari).

### Stop correlating stories to developers

Well, [Scrum doesn't have sub-Teams](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#scrum-team). So stop trying to assign stories to developers.

Story points are a *relative* estimate of *effort* for the *Team as a whole*. It's not really possible to convert story points to time. Primarily (though there are other reasons) because Story A with 2 points might take Alice 1 day but Bob 3 days, while Story B might take each of them 2 days, and both stories could be done by Charlie in half a day, or Dave in 2 weeks...

You *can* (kind of) use story point estimates for long-range time estimates, based on (and only on) **the Team's velocity**. But this is going to be a very *rough* estimate. With that in mind...

### Stop trying to give exact estimates for uncertain things

Take a look into the [Cone of Uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_of_Uncertainty). You're at the wide end of the cone but trying to pretend that the cone is a line. You have uncertainty, so be **realistic** and bake that uncertainty into your estimates.

It's better to say "It will take between 2 and 5 months" and be correct than to say "it will take 3 months" and have it take 4.

### You shouldn't have sub-Teams

> We do have sub-teams, because nobody is skilled enough to handle any type of User Story, but is skilled in a specific kind of User Story

You have misunderstood the purpose of not having sub-Teams. Of *course* different people have different skills. That's never going to change. The reason to never have sub-Teams *despite* that fact is because Scrum is all about the Team. The Team is atomic.

Trying to break the Team up into sub-Teams leads to problems such as:

- Trying to get overly-complex for estimates (everything about this thread right here)
- Assigning responsibility/blame to individuals
- Lack of cohesion - the Team members don't feel like members of a single Team. At best, they are coworkers; at worst, competitors.
- Team members stop caring about the parts of the Sprint not related to their Sub-Team

> stress for those skilled in devops and boredom for those in UI

See final bullet point above. Remove the sub-Teams and this problem should resolve itself as your Team members start working *together*.

### Use the Retrospective!

I could be wrong, but the vibe I'm getting is: "My Team ran into a problem. I assume the solution is X. How can I do X better and then force that on my Team?"

When what should be happening is: "My Team ran into a problem. I want to bring it up in the Retrospective to see their perspective and gather suggested fixes."

Comment: First of all: We might be at the conflict line between scrum and safe. What I am planning is a Programm Increment: https://innolution.com/resources/glossary/program-increment and I am not in the position to change that, so I need to plan ahead but still be flexible at the same time. Difficult but possible. Secondly about sub-teams: We do have sub-teams, because nobody is skilled enough to handle any type of User Story, but is skilled in a specific kind of User Story categorized in UI, BE & Devops. If got those kind of people please refer them to me ;).

Comment: Thirdly my problem is not the estimation of a Userstory. We can handle that. My Problem is the capacity/velocity of the team with those 3 categories. Why? Because I had sprints, where we ignored the category of devops and the sprint failed, because the guys responsible for devops have been overestimated, while the capacity for UI was underestimated. This resulted in stress for those skilled in devops and boredom for those in UI. And no, those in UI cannot be made into Devops-Engineers in a Sprint.

Comment: And lastly: This Answer does not answer the original question. The question tackles a practical problem when planning a PI regarding the question: How much time do we have for what? And who has what skills and which tasks can be done in which time frame? In essenz I just want to know how I can approximate and adapt the capacity of tasks in a specific category.

Comment: @telion 1-3: Updated my answer. 4: Correct. That is what a frame challenge means. You asked "I want X, how can I do Y?" I'm saying "Don't do Y."

Comment: About the subteams: Look If I have a team with Backend Developers with a techstack of Java & Springboot and a UI Webdevelopers with a Techstack of Vue, JS & Node.js, then I can't think of a retrospective that changes their techstack. Its like wanting a Chinese and an American to both become German, because the German Language is better in some aspects. But I have one Rockstar Programmers that can do both. Now I can just ignore that difference in plannings and just say we only do UI in the first sprint, and the Backend in the last, but that will fail both sprints.

Comment: The American and the Chinese can work together though. Maybe the analogy of cook and waitress is better. They work together in a team but have different skills and therefore different tasks. Maybe I only need 3 cooks and 10 waitresses. But I don't need 10 cooks and 3 waitresses. Maybe one waitress is able to cook a bit but only in emergencies. Now I am far from the position of hiring or firing people. I just need to know, what my team is probably capable of and what not, because my clients want to know when what feature can be used...

Comment: @telion "I can't think of a retrospective that changes their techstack" - you're still having a fundamental misunderstanding. You're still trying to push a solution on the Team 'more granular estimates' or 'change their techstack' without consulting the Team in the Retrospective. Nowhere did I suggest that the solution is to change their tech stack - my point in that paragraph is *do not just straight to a solution*. Instead bring up the problem in the Retro and discuss. It's not your job to define the process. It's the Team's.

Comment: @telion "Now I can just ignore that difference in plannings and just say we only do UI in the first sprint, and the Backend in the last" No,  if you are doing Scrum, then ***you*** are ***not*** the one picking what goes into the Sprint. ***The Team is***. And they will, over time, get good at pulling in the right amount of work despite confounding factors such as uneven workload.

Comment: Correct, the Team is picking the tasks. But who is creating those? If I create an Epic, lets call it "Migration from Kubernetes to Openshift" and one called "Create Landing Page for X". Now lets have 20 Epics. Now my clients ask me: "When do I get what?", Now me and my team gonna plan that. Especially when I have to account for some deadlines for some of the clients (which can easily be accounted for if you think ahead for 2 sprints). And the ways it stands now, if I don't have the overview, no one will. It's also not like pick dev A for US X. But can the PI even work is the question?

Comment: Also we don't really have a blame-game (unless someone did something on purpose). We all know about Prodfires, Bugs, Issues, miss planning, mismanagement, etc. which are all good reasons to be late. But If can already say that we have a lot to much work or to less, then I should. And to do that, properly I need estimated US, Team velocity, and capacity per category per sprint. Also in sprint planning, I can know immediately if the team has time for the new US that is needed.

Comment: Suppose you have a planned sprint, with 20 Tasks, how can anyone have the confidence to say the sprint (2 weeks) will work without looking at these kinds of numbers. I mean nobody has the overview over who has how much holiday, work in another project, other events. So without this overview, we cannot have a successful sprint, meaning one where we neither overloaded nor underloaded (in some margin of course). This is not Kanban after all.

Comment: @telion "I mean nobody has the overview over who has how much holiday, work in another project, other events" **The team has**, at least for the first few sprints. And that's what you have a scrum master for as well - to have that info present.